# Node js insert Mysql doesnt work

Tags: mysql, insert

this is part of the code i use

```
var insertedData = {
        name: 'testname',
        score: '1337'
    };
connect.query('INSERT INTO table SET ?', insertedData, function(error, result){
```

and this is the error i got

> { [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'table SET `name` = 'Hek', `score` = '12'' at line
>   1]code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR', errno: 1064, sqlState: '42000',index: 0 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` is a reserved word in MySQL. I'd advise to rename your table to something else. If this is absolutely not a possibility for you, you can escape it with backticks:

```
connect.query('INSERT INTO `table` SET ?', insertedData, function(error, result){
```

Comment: Good find, but its an insert statement actually. Still incorrect

Comment: @Shaharyar `INSERT ... SET` is a valid syntax in MySQL. It's not standard ANSI, but it's perfectly fine for MySQL.